# Create new column "Weekday %H:%M" from Timestamp

Tags: r

I have some columns (timestamp, object_id, status and some others) with which I want to predict the status of an object.
I have the hypothesis that the "weektime" has an important influence on the status. Under "weektime" I understand: Monday 23:17.
Now I think I need to create a column with this format to test the hypothesis.

I already converted the timestamp to POSIXlt:

```
training_data$TimeStamp = as.POSIXlt(training_data$TimeStamp, "", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

I also already created a column with only the weekday.

```
training_data$TimeStamp_weekday = weekdays(training_data$TimeStamp)
```

Can you help me to create a column with the "weektime"?

I think I also need to have only 4 "time slots" of 15min per hour to make the predictions easier. So Monday 23:17 -> 23:15

```
0-15 mins -> 0
15-30 mins -> 15
30-45 mins -> 30
45-60 mins -> 45
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to solve the problem first, and then post code that you tried that didn't work. Posters here expect to critique existing code.

Comment: the [`ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) function may be useful here.

Comment: See ?strptime. I'm pretty sure you can get weekdays with a format spec.Also you need to realize that 0 minutes and 60 minutes are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to paste anything on to lubridate::weekday results. There is a trunc.POSIXt but it doesn't let you truncate to fractional intervals as far as I can tell. Instead truncate to the prior 15 minute mark by subtracting 7.5 minutes (=.0.125 hours), dividing by the same amount, rounding and then multiplying by that amount. That should have the effect of "rounding down" to the prior interval mark. Then use format.POSIXt to get the desired format.

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2017-12-29 12:24:49 PST"
> 
format( as.POSIXct( to convert back to datetime
  round( as.numeric( Sys.time() -0.125 * 60*60 )/(0.125 * 60*60) ) * 0.125*60*60 , 
           origin="1970-01-01"), "%A %H:%M")
[1] "Friday 12:15"
```

What is does is shift all the times so they are centered on the interval "marks" or boundaries, then rounds to the nearest whole number on that scale, and then expands back to the original scale.